# Node.js: waiting for callbacks in a loop before moving on

Tags: asynchronous, node.js

I have a loop that has an asynchronous call inside it, with a callback. To be able to move on, I need the callback to fire for the entire loop all the way through, to then display the results of the loop.

Every way I've tried to control this doesn't work (have tried Step, Tame.js, async.js, and others) - any suggestions on how to move forward?

```
array = ['test', 'of', 'file'];
array2 = ['another', 'array'];

for(i in array) {
    item = array[i];
    document_ids = new Array();

    for (i2 in array2) {
        item2 = array2[i2];
        // look it up
        mongodb.find({item_name: item2}).toArray(function(err, documents {
            // because of async,
            // the code moves on and calls this back later
            console.log('got id');
            document_ids.push(document_id);
        }))
    }

    // use document_ids
    console.log(document_ids); // shows []
    console.log('done');
}

// shows:
// []
// done
// got id
// got id
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You're logging document_ids before your callbacks fire. You have to keep track of how many callbacks you've run to know when you're done.

An easy method is to use a counter, and to check the count on each callback.

Taking your example

```
var array = ['test', 'of', 'file'];
var array2 = ['another', 'array'];
var document_ids = [];

var waiting = 0;

for(i in array) {
    item = array[i];

    for (i2 in array2) {
        item2 = array2[i2];
        waiting ++;

        mongodb.find({item_name: item2}).toArray(
            function(err, document_id) {
                waiting --;
                document_ids.push(document_id);
                complete();
            })
        );
    }
}

function complete() {
    if (!waiting) {
        console.log(document_ids);
        console.log('done');    
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much! I modified this with help of async.js and got it working.

Comment: It is working fine just want to know like why you are using `waiting --;`
And I think the comment on every line should be good

Comment: @AnilYadav he is using waiting --; on every line to decrement the value in every callback and finally it will be 0. And if the condition inside the complete function will be satisfied.