# Node async callback: How to return an object within a loop in a callback?

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, callback, asynccallback

My basic question is similar to this [previous post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8731459/node-js-how-to-properly-return-an-object-from-within-a-callback), except that I also have two loops going within my callback (to grab data from two arrays and eventually return an array of json objects in the browser). Here is my code:

```
router.get('/users', function(req, res) {
userColl.find().toArray(function (err, items) {

    if (err) {console.log(err + ': err');} else {
        var userlist = [];

        items.forEach(function (dj) {

            showColl.find({hostId: dj._id}).toArray(function (err, shows) {
                if (err) {console.log('showFind error: ' + err);} else {

                    shows.forEach( function (show) {
                        userlist.push(
                            {
                               _id: dj._id,
                               access: dj.access,
                               firstName: dj.firstName,
                               lastName: dj.lastName,
                               gradYear: dj.gradYear,
                               shows: show.showTitle,
                               show_id: show._id
                            }
                        );
                        // ===============  SPOT #2  =============
                    }); //  end shows loop
                }
            }); // end showColl.find
        }); //  end items.forEach

        console.log(JSON.stringify(userlist) + ' ul');
        res.render('admin/users/manageUsers', {
            "userlist" : userlist,
            title: 'view users'
        });
    }   // end if/else      
}); // end userColl.find callback   
});
```

I assumed that what I have would work, and it returns no errors, but since it's asynchronous the `userlist` variable is blank when the page is rendered. If I put the render command in the show loop (SPOT #2) it renders the page after just the first loop, so I have one item instead of the dozens that I'm expecting. If I put the render call anywhere in between its current location and SPOT #2 I get an error for calling multiple responses. Is there any way to delay the render command until the callback has been complete *without* placing it in the callback? Any advice much appreciated.

Comment: Only send the response if `userlist.length === items.length`. In the long run, you might want to look at something like the `async` module: https://github.com/caolan/async#each

Comment: Another duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/q/6756404/218196, http://stackoverflow.com/q/6673717/218196, http://stackoverflow.com/q/10551499/218196

Comment: And this seems to be a popular one: http://stackoverflow.com/q/4631774/218196